В чем причина ошибки SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED?
В чем причина ошибки:
(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificat
e verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)'))

Сначала подумал сертификат протух - проверил на сайте https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html
Сайт говорит, что норм. Решил сделать запрос с локалки - запрос проходит. А вот из микросервиса - не проходит. В чем может быть проблема и куда копать?
UPDATE:
Зашел с другого ПК на сайт куда делается запрос - в браузере горит красным - говорит сертификат умер. Решаил еще раз проверить через https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html - он мне говрит, что сертификат еще валиден 33 дня будет.
Решил на вский случай перегенерировать сертификат, для сервиса, на котором через браузер горит красным:
sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html/ -d yourdomain.com -d www.yourdomain.com

В итоге не дает сгенерироавть и выдает ошибку:

To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain contain(s) the right IP address

Написал в ТП, у кого арендую VDS - те по партизански молчат уже 5 часов.
Куда мне копать?

Вероятно, корневые сертификаты устарели на хосте, где запускаете

где запускается - там только в 2025 году истекет

Корневой сертификат сайта, куда вы стучитесь.

Интересная особенность - если зайти через браузер - то да, горит красным, а если проверять через https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html - то говорит что все ок.
Решил попробовать перегенерировать через команду  sudo certbot certonly --webroot -w /var/www/html/ -d yourdomain.com -d www.yourdomain.com
Стало ругаться что To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
contain(s) the right IP address.

Ну вы хоть напишите прямо в вопросе - в каком коде и в какой момент возникает эта ошибка? Сейчас её контекст совершенно непонятен.

@CrazyElf, обновил

Стало лучше, но всё-равно непонятно. Что делаете то когда ошибка возникает? requests.get или что?

Вообщем на VDS_1 крутится сервис - у него сертификат до 2025 года,  на котором крутится СЕРВИС_1 и стучится на СЕРВИС_2, который находится на VDS_2. У сервиса на VDS_2 горит через браузер красным сертификат, а если sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html проверить, то он говорит, что еще 33 дня есть. Я даже на VDS_1 сделал тупо скрипт с запросом на СЕРВИС_2 и этот скрипт тоже дал ошибку SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Какая-то дичь - через Хром показывает красным, через Яндекс также как и sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html показывает, что еще 33 дня есть...

Ну может он правда не экспайренный, а какая-то другая причина. Это вот и прочее такое читали? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77443265/8324991

Ну как минимум в «красном» браузере должно быть легко посмотреть, на что конкретно он ругается (если браузер считает что срок истёк, значит через этот же браузер посмотреть сроки всех сертификатов в цепочке)

Дату/время бы ещё проверить на всех серверах.

Кстати еще заметил такой момент, что хром у меня все сервисы от яндекса отрубил - как-будто я вышел из них и не предлагает теперь QR-код для входа.... Может, проблема вообще не там, где я ищу? Хотя тогда причем тут python?
